# QT download video with SSL not working

Tags: qt, ssl, video, download

This code downloads a video, but for some reason does not work

globals.h

```
QString videoDirectLink = "";
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "globals.h"



void MainWindow::readOutput() {

        QByteArray outData = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();  // read from CMD
        videoDirectLink = outData; //  videoDirectLink Contains https://media08.vbox7.com/s/91/91f4c651car96dafe736.mp4

        if (videoDirectLink.contains("https")) {
            // SSL downloading
            QNetworkAccessManager *manager2 = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
            connect(manager2, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
            QNetworkRequest *req = new QNetworkRequest();
            req->setUrl(QUrl(videoDirectLink));  //videoDirectLink
            QSslConfiguration configSsl = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
            configSsl.setProtocol(QSsl::AnyProtocol);
            req->setSslConfiguration(configSsl);

            connect(manager2->get(*req), SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64))); 
    }
```

If changes `req->setUrl(QUrl(videoDirectLink));`
to `req->setUrl(QUrl("https://media08.vbox7.com/s/91/91f4c651car96dafe736.mp4"));` 
or

```
QString n ="https://media08.vbox7.com/s/91/91f4c651car96dafe736.mp4";
req->setUrl(QUrl(n));
```

everything works

This is worked code for download without SSL. The principle is the same

globals.h

```
QString videoDirectLink = "";
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "globals.h"
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    // start downloading
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    QString target = videoDirectLink;
    QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded(target.toLocal8Bit());
    connect(manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url)), SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
```

I tried to add encoding, but that is not the problem.
other suggestions ?

// NOT WORKING

```
 void MainWindow::readOutput() {

        QString outData = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();  // URL -> https://www.vbox7.com/play:91f4c651ca
        videoDirectLink = outData; //  videoDirectLink -> https://media28.vbox7.com/s/91/91f4c651car96dafe736.mp4

        if (videoDirectLink.contains("https")) {


            QNetworkAccessManager *manager2 = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
            connect(manager2, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
            QNetworkRequest *req = new QNetworkRequest();
            req->setUrl(QUrl(videoDirectLink));  //videoDirectLink
            connect(manager2->get(*req), SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
            QMessageBox::information(this,"SSL downloading",videoDirectLink,"ok"); // displays https://media28.vbox7.com/s/91/91f4c651car96dafe736.mp4

        }
    }
```

Comment: do ```qDebug() << QUrl(videoDirectLink);``` to console, compare printed result and URL string which is working fine for you

Comment: @Max Go i tried QMessageBox::information(this,"sal",videoDirectLink,"ok"); and result is OK.  but does not work

Comment: I meant, that you need to compare what is passed into ```req->setUrl``` in both cases: in working and non working.

Comment: @Max Go i did that they match, but not working

Comment: You don't need to specify additionally QSslConfiguration ... just remove all lines related to this. Default settings works fine just if you put "https" protocol as part of your URL.

Comment: @Max Go  
I found the problem. I just remove new line from videoDirectLink

 QString directVideoLinkCleaned =
 videoDirectLink.remove(QRegExp("[\\n\\t\\r]")); 
thank you for your cooperation